# Included ConstraintLayout with merge tag doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

This is my qff_layout.xml file

```
<merge
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/questions_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/questions"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/followers_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/followers_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/followers"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/questions_label"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/following_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/following_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/following"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/followers_label"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/questions_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/questions_label"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/questions_label"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questions_label"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/followers_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/questions_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/following_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/followers_label"/>


    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/following_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="0"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/following_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/following_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/following_label"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</merge>
```

This displays 6 textviews in two rows, something you would see in instagram app in profile section with Posts-Followers-Following and bellow numbers under each of those.
Now the problem is when I include that in my main layout which is ConstraintLayout:
profile_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/secondaryDarkColor"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image"/>

    <include
            layout="@layout/qff_layout"
            android:id="@+id/qff_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primaryLightColor"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/qff_layout"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sliding_tabs" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Nothing gets displayed.
I tried changing my main layout to linear and it's the same.
But when I remove merge tag from qff_layout.xml and use the same include tag in main layout it works well and displays the qff_layout, How??Why??
What is the use of merge tag then, please do not quote something from the stupidest documentation ever because it makes no sense.

Comment: could please share your main layout as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use merge when you dont want to repeat same ViewGroup. In this case, it could save you from not using two nested ConstraintLayouts - you could remove ConstraintLayout from qff_layout.xml and use merge as your root element like:

```
<merge
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- your text view -->
</merge>
```

If your ConstraintLayout in qff_layout.xml has some other purpose, you just leave it, and include qff_layout.xml without merge as root element.

In other words merge purpose is to replace root ViewGroup.
Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts).

**UPDATE:**

You can fix your XML this way without removing marge.

Positioning constraints you defined on  element, should be also applied on your ConstraintLayout inside qff_layout.xml like:

```
<merge
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/qff_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <!-- your text view -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</merge>
```

Why you need to apply this: When you put layout inside  element it will basically get pasted in the line you include it. When you don't define constraints for some layout inside ConstraintLyout, it jumps to the top left corner of the screen and thats what happend to layout you included. It didnt have defined constraints inside qff_layout.xml that will apply when it gets included, so it jumped to the top left corner.

Comment: how are you positioning elements if you remove constraint layout as root in merge

Comment: If you position elements correctly in your main layout (that has Constraint Layout as root) and than move them to separate (with constraints defined) layout with marge root, when you include them back inside main layout, they will be positioned correctly. However, if you need to include qff_layout.xml in multiple layouts that have different structure and elements id-s, this wont work. In that case, you dont have any use of merge.

Comment: in that second case you mentioned, should I use layout without merge and just include it

Comment: Yes, without merge layout. In qff_layout.xml ConstraintLayout should be root element and just include it in other layout.